# Comparing two excel files and putting the difference in a new sheet

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am comparing two sheets that are like this:

[image: excel sheets]

One sheet is newer than the other and can have a row removed, added, or updated.

My code to detect if a row is removed/added between the two is not working for me, here is what I have:

```
Private Sub CompareSpreadsheets()
    Dim xlApp1 As Excel.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
    Dim xlApp2 As Excel.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
    Dim xlApp3 As Excel.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
    Dim xlWorkBook1, xlWorkBook2, xlWorkBook3 As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet1, xlWorkSheet2, xlWorkSheet3 As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim xlRange1 As Excel.Range
    Dim maxRows As Short
    Dim qtyChange, mtlChange, newItem, delItem As Boolean
    Dim newRowCount As Short = 1
    Dim w3row As Short = 1

    'Check if Excel is installed on system
    If xlApp1 Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Excel is missing/not properly installed on your system.", "ERROR")
        Return
    End If

    xlApp1.Workbooks.Open(path1)
    xlWorkBook1 = xlApp1.ActiveWorkbook
    xlWorkSheet1 = xlWorkBook1.ActiveSheet

    xlApp2.Workbooks.Open(path2)
    xlWorkBook2 = xlApp2.ActiveWorkbook
    xlWorkSheet2 = xlWorkBook2.ActiveSheet

    'Get maximum number of columns and rows from new spreadsheet
    maxRows = xlWorkSheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    pbStatus.Minimum = 1
    pbStatus.Maximum = maxRows

    xlWorkBook3 = xlApp3.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
    xlWorkSheet3 = xlWorkBook3.Sheets("sheet1")

    qtyChange = False
    mtlChange = False
    newItem = False
    delItem = False

    Dim counter = 0 '/temp

    For i As Short = 1 To maxRows
        pbStatus.Value = i

        '[-- Green = Quantity change
        'Yellow = Material change
        'Blue = New item
        'Red = Deleted item --]

        If GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 3) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 3) And _
            GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 4) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 4) And _
            GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 5) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 5) And _
            GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 6) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 6) And _
            GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 7) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 7) And _
            GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 8) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 8) Then
            'DONE
            qtyChange = False
            mtlChange = False
            newItem = False
            delItem = False
            newRowCount += 1
        ElseIf GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 3) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 3) And _
            GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 4) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 4) And _
            GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 5) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 5) And _
            GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 6) <> GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 6) And _
            GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 7) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 7) And _
            GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 8) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 8) Then
            'DONE
            qtyChange = True
        ElseIf GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 1) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 1) And _
            GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 2) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 2) And _
            GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 3) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 3) And _
            GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 4) <> GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 4) And _
            GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 5) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 5) And _
            GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 6) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 6) And _
            GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 7) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 7) And _
            GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 8) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 8) Then
            'DONE
            mtlChange = True
        ElseIf GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 3) <> GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 3) And _
            GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 4) <> GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 4) Then

            If GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount + 1, 4) <> GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 4) Then
                newItem = True
            ElseIf GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 4) <> GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i + 1, 4) Then
                delItem = True
            End If
        End If

        'Procedure for each case
        If qtyChange Then
            xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 1) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 1)
            xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 1), Excel.Range)
            xlRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green

            xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 2) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 2)
            xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 2), Excel.Range)
            xlRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green

            xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 3) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 3)
            xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 3), Excel.Range)
            xlRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green

            xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 4) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 4)
            xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 4), Excel.Range)
            xlRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green

            xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 5) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 5)
            xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 5), Excel.Range)
            xlRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green

            xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 6) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 6)
            xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 6), Excel.Range)
            xlRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green

            xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 7) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 7)
            xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 7), Excel.Range)
            xlRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green

            xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 8) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 8)
            xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 8), Excel.Range)
            xlRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green

            newRowCount += 1
            w3row += 1
        ElseIf mtlChange Then
            xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 1) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 1)
            xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 1), Excel.Range)
            xlRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow

            xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 2) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 2)
            xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 2), Excel.Range)
            xlRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow

            xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 3) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 3)
            xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 3), Excel.Range)
            xlRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow

            xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 4) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 4)
            xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 4), Excel.Range)
            xlRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow

            xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 5) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 5)
            xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 5), Excel.Range)
            xlRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow

            xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 6) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 6)
            xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 6), Excel.Range)
            xlRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow

            xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 7) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 7)
            xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 7), Excel.Range)
            xlRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow

            xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 8) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 8)
            xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 8), Excel.Range)
            xlRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow

            newRowCount += 1
            w3row += 1
        ElseIf delItem Then
            xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 1) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 1)
            xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 1), Excel.Range)
            xlRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red

            xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 2) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 2)
            xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 2), Excel.Range)
            xlRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red

            xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 3) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 3)
            xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 3), Excel.Range)
            xlRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red

            xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 4) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 4)
            xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 4), Excel.Range)
            xlRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red

            xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 5) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 5)
            xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 5), Excel.Range)
            xlRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red

            xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 6) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 6)
            xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 6), Excel.Range)
            xlRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red

            xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 7) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 7)
            xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 7), Excel.Range)
            xlRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red

            xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 8) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 8)
            xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 8), Excel.Range)
            xlRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red

            newRowCount += 1
            i -= 1
            w3row += 1
        ElseIf newItem Then
            xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 1) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 1)
            xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 1), Excel.Range)
            xlRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Blue

            xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 2) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 2)
            xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 2), Excel.Range)
            xlRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Blue

            xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 3) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 3)
            xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 3), Excel.Range)
            xlRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Blue

            xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 4) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 4)
            xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 4), Excel.Range)
            xlRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Blue

            xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 5) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 5)
            xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 5), Excel.Range)
            xlRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Blue

            xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 6) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 6)
            xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 6), Excel.Range)
            xlRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Blue

            xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 7) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 7)
            xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 7), Excel.Range)
            xlRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Blue

            xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 8) = GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 8)
            xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet3.Cells(w3row, 8), Excel.Range)
            xlRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Blue

            w3row += 1
        End If

        qtyChange = False
        mtlChange = False
        newItem = False
        delItem = False
    Next

    'Save new spreadsheet [TEMP NAME]
    xlWorkBook3.SaveAs("C:\Users\Windows\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\test.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, _
                Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue)
    xlWorkBook3.Close(True, misValue, misValue)
    xlApp3.Quit()

    '----------------------------------
    'End of process, cleaning up CPU---
    xlWorkBook1.Close(True, misValue, misValue)
    xlApp1.Quit()

    xlWorkBook2.Close(True, misValue, misValue)
    xlApp2.Quit()

    ReleaseObject(xlWorkSheet1)
    ReleaseObject(xlWorkBook1)
    ReleaseObject(xlApp1)

    ReleaseObject(xlWorkSheet2)
    ReleaseObject(xlWorkBook2)
    ReleaseObject(xlApp2)

    ReleaseObject(xlWorkSheet3)
    ReleaseObject(xlWorkBook3)
    ReleaseObject(xlApp3)

    cmdFormat.Text = "Process complete. Compare new files?"
End Sub
```

EDIT: What's not working? It will skip identical rows fine and also detect the cell changes (I have column 4 and 6 set which return them as green/yellow) but once my code finds a deleted entry in the old worksheet/new entry in the new sheet it messes up.

Here is where I believe it is messing up:

```
ElseIf GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 3) <> GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 3) And _
        GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 4) <> GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 4) Then

        If GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount + 1, 4) <> GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i, 4) Then
            newItem = True
        ElseIf GetCellData(xlWorkSheet1, newRowCount, 4) <> GetCellData(xlWorkSheet2, i + 1, 4) Then
            delItem = True
        End If
    End If
```

If anyone can see the issue please let me know. Or if you have another solution to this. Thanks!

Comment: How is it not working?  We need specifics.  Your wall of text is very intimidating.

Comment: I'll edit it with a better explanation and also add the entire code sub. @ryanyuyu

Comment: any time you are tinkering with the for loop counter like that, it can get weird. Your logic says "If the Next Row of Sheet1 DOESN'T equal the Current Row of Sheet2, then it is a new item. If The current row of Sheet1 doesn't equal the Next row of Sheet2, then it is a deleted item. It seems kind of backwards. Also, say you have a new item followed by a deleted item. Isn't that going to break everything?

Comment: @user1274820 in regards to reaching a new item followed by a deleted item... you're right. It's what is breaking everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I haven't been more help. It's definitely a little tricky. I would have personally pulled each sheet into datatables and compared them there. That's what I use for determining New/Completed QA's on my program between two sets of data:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/36pZS.png

I ended up doing things a little differently than you.

I pull the data I need from the excel files into a data table using this method.

It's a lot faster than reading each row one at a time using excel interop.

Grab excel data and use it to populate a DataTable:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//This function is absolute magic >.> - Fill DataTable with excel spreadsheet
//HDR=YES means "Spreadsheet has headers" Change to NO if not.
//name = "Log"; - This is the Sheet name to pull the data from
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//oconn takes an SQL like command (Select Everything from name sheet) using con
//HDR=YES means that our data has headers :)
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + copyToPath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;';";
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [Log$]", con);
con.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
DataTable data = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(data);
con.Close();
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

This leaves us with a DataTable that contains all the rows/headers for an excel spreadsheet.

Then, we can pull in the second one using the same method.

At that point, we will be able to compare the data in C# which is a lot faster in my experience.

Finally, you can export to excel using Excel Interop and you'll only have to open one instance.

Comment: Yes - there needs to be a better way than decrementing your for loop i variable. I'm trying to wrap my head around it without being able to try anything myself.

Comment: Basically saying, if you find two cells that don't match - check the ones below it. If NEITHER of those two match, then what you have is both a New Item and a Deleted item, add them both, and continue. Of course, this assumes that you won't add/delete multiple items concurrently. This may not be the case. It's really best to loop through each file to find matches or not find matches. This is easiest to do with a key, but you can do with your current data.

Comment: I'll be back in an hour, sorry I haven't been able to help you more. It's just not as simple as you are trying to make it with your flags. New Item and Deleted Item is hard to determine. You have to search the entire document of Sheet 2 to determine if an item is indeed "Deleted" Likewise, you have to do the same to determine if it is actually "New".

Comment: Thanks for the cool function. I'll set what I have aside and work on a new solution using this code.

Comment: Hey man, sorry I wasn't able to figure it out with you v.v I am still looking at it, but work keeps popping up

Comment: You have been a major help already. I'm using the function you provided (a bit of tweaking done) and it's blazing fast compared to the excel object.